# Minecraft Corrupt Jar After Deleting Meta-inf

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-optifine

I'm trying to install OptiFine on minecraft and I'm taking the following steps:

1. Open minecraft with archive manager
2. Delete the Meta-Inf folder
3. Open OptiFine with archive manager
4. Copy contents of OptiFine to minecraft archive
5. Close both archives
6. Open minecraft with `java -jar minecraft.jar`
7. At this point I get `Invalid or corrupt jarfile minecraft(1) (copy).jar!

Even just deleting the meta-inf folder gives me this error. I'm on linux mint 12. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem may be outside the minecraft.jar. Try this: backup your .minecraft folder; delete it; load fresh minecraft; do what you wanted to do.

Comment: What archive manager are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must rename it to: `minecraft.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your jar is named `minecraft.jar`

I would suggest deleting your bin folder and letting Minecraft download a fresh copy before trying this again.